# Rails 4.2: Unable to intergrate WYSIWYG editor for Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Installed the Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails gem to create a WYSIWYG editor. So a user can add content in the text area. I have added the editor in the content field.

**_form.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
      <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> Prevented this post from saving: </h2>
        <ul>
          <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>

        <br>
        <br>

        <%= f.label :content, "Write your article here" %><br>
        **<%= f.text_area :content, as: :wysihtml5 %>**

        <br>
        <br>

        <%= f.submit %>

      <% end %>
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'pygments.rb', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.2.2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails', github: 'nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.7'
gem 'coderay'
```

**updated the application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

and imported the file into my application.css.scss

```
@import "normalize";
  @import "welcome";
  @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
  @import "bootstrap";
  @import "articles";
  @import "bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5";
```

But after restarting the server the WYSIWYG editor does not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the option `as: :wysihtml5` with default form helper of Rails will not work as I only see the author of this gem say it will work with `simple_form`.

You can try to active the editor by javascript (place this below your application.js)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wysihtml5').each(function(i, elem) {
        $(elem).wysihtml5();
    });
})
```

And change `<%= f.text_area :content, as: :wysihtml5 %>` to

`<%= f.text_area :content, class: "wysihtml5" %>`